# How do I update a RecyclerView on sorting the data?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My database (Firestore) stores `Chart`s, created by `User`s.

On opening the app, the `User` is shown their own `Charts`, sorted by Chart Name (this is displayed in a Fragment called `MyChartsFragment`). They can click a button to change the sort field; this should retrieve the same list of `Charts`, but sorted by the selected field.

I'm able to pass the new sort field name into `MyChartsFragment`, but at that point the list of `Charts` goes blank.  I assume I need to redraw it somehow.

The `MyChartsFragment` is as follows (I've removed most of the try-catch blocks, error checks etc, for clarity):

```
public class FragmentMyCharts extends FragmentChartsList {

    public FragmentMyCharts() {}

    public Query getQuery(FirebaseFirestore databaseReference, String orderBy) {
        // Specify the query which is used to retrieve this user's charts
        return databaseReference.collection("charts")
                .whereEqualTo("uid", getUid())
                .orderBy(orderBy);
    }
}
```

This extends `FragmentChartsList`, which contains:

```
public abstract class FragmentChartsList extends Fragment {

    private FirebaseFirestore mDatabaseRef;
    private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Chart, ChartViewHolder> mAdapter;
    private Query mChartsQuery;
    private RecyclerView mRecycler;
    private String mOrder = "name";

    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    ToolbarFragmentListCharts mFragmentTLC;

    public FragmentChartsList() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        // Inflate layout, and find Recycler View to hold the list
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_charts_list, container, false);

        mRecycler = rootView.findViewById(R.id.charts_list);
        mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // Set up Layout Manager, and set Recycler View to use it
        LinearLayoutManager mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mManager);

        // Connect to the database, and get the appropriate query
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mChartsQuery = getQuery(mDatabaseRef, mOrder);

        // Set up Recycler Adapter
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Chart> recyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Chart>()
                .setQuery(mChartsQuery, Chart.class)
                .build();

        mAdapter = new ChartListAdapter(recyclerOptions, this.getActivity());

        // Use Recycler Adapter in RecyclerView
        mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Add listener to charts collection, and deal with any changes by re-showing the list
        mChartsQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots,
                                @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null && queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                    ((MainActivity) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).setPage(1);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAdapter.startListening();
    }

    public void setOrderField(String order) {
        mOrder = order;
        mChartsQuery = getQuery(mDatabaseRef, mOrder);

        // Set up Recycler Adapter
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Chart> recyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Chart>()
                .setQuery(mChartsQuery, Chart.class)
                .build();

        mAdapter = new ChartListAdapter(recyclerOptions, this.getActivity());

        // Use Recycler Adapter in RecyclerView
        mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    public abstract Query getQuery(FirebaseFirestore databaseReference, String orderBy);

}
```

So, when the main activity is notified by the toolbar that the sort field has changed, it retrieves the MyChartsFragment (as a FragmentChartsList) and calls the setOrderField function:

```
public void setOrder(String order) {

        FragmentChartsList myCharts = (FragmentChartsList) mPagerAdapter.getItem(0);
        myCharts.setOrderField(order);

    }
```

This appears to update the value of mOrder correctly, but then it doesn't re-display the RecyclerView, so I just get a blank space.

What am I doing wrong?

EDITED TO ADD DETAIL:

My `ChartListAdapter` class is:

```
public class ChartListAdapter
        extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Chart, ChartViewHolder> {

    private Activity mActivity;
    private FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Chart> recyclerOptions;

    public ChartListAdapter(FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Chart> recyclerOptions, Activity activity) {
        super(recyclerOptions);

        mActivity = activity;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChartViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Chart model) {

        final String chartKey = this.getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId();

        model.setKey(chartKey);

        // Set click listener for the chart
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, ActivityViewChart.class);
                intent.putExtra("ChartKey", chartKey);
                mActivity.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // Implement long-click menu
        mActivity.registerForContextMenu(holder.itemView);

        // Bind Chart to ViewHolder
        holder.bindToChart(model);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ChartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_chart, parent, false);

        return new ChartViewHolder(view);
    }

    public void setRecyclerOptions(FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Chart> recyclerOptions) {
        this.recyclerOptions = recyclerOptions;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved... in `setOrderField` I was declaring a new `mAdapter`, but not listening to it.  Once I added

`mAdapter.startListening()`

it all worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

rather then recreating the recyclerView adapter, try updating the options in the adapter.

```
public void setOrderField(String order) {
        mOrder = order;
        mChartsQuery = getQuery(mDatabaseRef, mOrder);

        // Set up Recycler Adapter
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Chart> recyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Chart>()
                .setQuery(mChartsQuery, Chart.class)
                .build();


        // Use Recycler Adapter in RecyclerView
        mAdapter.setRecyclerOptions(recyclerOptions);

       // then call the notify data set changed on the adapter to recreate the recyclerView elements
       mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and in the recyclerView adapter class, add a setter for the recyclerOptions :

```
public void setRecyclerOptions(FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Chart> recyclerOptions) {
       this.recyclerOptions = recyclerOptions;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I've done as you suggested, but FragmentChartsList isn't recognising mAdapter.setRecyclerOptions(recyclerOptions) - I'm getting a "Cannot resolve method" error. I didn't previously have the recyclerOptions variable in the adapter, so I've added it in - not sure whether I'm meant to be doing anything else to it? I've added my Adapter class into my original question, in case it's relevant... what am I doing wrong there?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you share a link to github or other source with your code in it ?

Comment: I've created a Git repo with the relevant files in it.  Can I send you a link via private message?  Don't want to post it publicly. Thanks.

Comment: if you still have problems then share it, and i will see what i can do

Answer (score 0):

Found one problem... I had declared `mAdapter` with:

```
private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Chart, ChartViewHolder> mAdapter;
```

when it should have been:

```
private ChartListAdapter mAdapter;
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2021:**

I don't know, for how long this new method works, but I'm so thankful for finding it out by myself, because I couldn't find any good response to that:

You don't have to create any Methods in your Adapter anymore.
Simply create the setOrder Method like this:

```
public FirestoreRecyclerOptions<event_log_Item> getOrder(String order){
    String mOrder = order;
    Query query = current_productRef.orderBy(mOrder, Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<event_log_Item> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<event_log_Item>().setQuery(query, event_log_Item.class).build();

    return options;
}
```

This Method will return the order-options for the field you want.

Then simply do:

```
mAdapter.updateOptions(setOrder("Timestamp"));
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The Method **"updateOptions"** is already implemented. Just simply give it the option you want and add **"notifyDataSetChanged();"**